# Visual Basic minimum 5 characters validation

Tags: vb.net, validation, character

How would I go about making sure that when a user inputs his "Combination" into the input box, it has to be at least 5 characters?

This is what code I have so far:

```
If (tboxStatus.Text) = "Combination Not Set" Or (tboxStatus.Text) = "UnLocked" Then
  Combination = CInt(InputBox("Set the Combination First"))
  tboxStatus.Text = "Locked"
ElseIf (tboxStatus.Text) = "Locked" Then
  MsgBox("You must first UnLock the safe before trying to change the combination.")
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters...

```
Dim value as String = InputBox("Set the Combination First")
If (value.Trim.Length < 5) Then
    MsgBox ("Combination must be at least 5 characters")
Else
    Combination = CInt(value)
End If
```

Among other things, you'll need to check if it's numeric before doing a CInt()

Answer (score 0):

```
If tboxStatus.Text = "Combination Not Set" OrElse tboxStatus.Text = "UnLocked" Then
    Dim result As String = ""

    While String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result) OrElse Not Integer.TryParse(result, Combination)
       result= InputBox("Set a Combination Number First")
    End While

    tboxStatus.Text = "Locked"

ElseIf tboxStatus.Text = "Locked" Then
    MsgBox("You must first UnLock the safe before trying to change the combination.")
End If
```